# How can I troubleshoot a network that I think is slow with macOS Monterey?

Tags: macos, imac, internet, monterey

I have a 2020 iMac 27 inch with macOS Monterey. My network is very slow - 10mbps upload and 337 Kbps down. My MacBook could achieve 30 Mbps download and 100mbps upload.

I'm also not able to connect to my 5G network, yet my other devices can. What issue could I be facing here and how can I fix it?

specs:

[image: specs]
[image]

Comment: Are there other devices nearby which could interfere? Can you try with Ethernet instead of WLAN/5G?

Comment: no, but I can't use ethernet because I'm in my bedroom which is not too far from the router. if the network is faster in my other devices  is imac is situated how can my imac alone have slow wi-fi even though it has better hardware?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok probably I just needed to reset my Mac. that solved the issue really well.